# Smoother swipe/gesture CSS transition animation

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I'm currently creating a small, simple web app in which the user can create several questions, they can then go to get an answer which will display a list of their questions.

By swiping the item (using hammer.js), the item transitions left 65px revealing a trash icon allowing them to delete the question, similar to how you can swipe to delete list items on iOS.

However, when swiping, if the user has several questions in which they could scroll down the body of the page, when swiping left to delete a question, the page sometimes tends to scroll vertically too, this vertical page scroll mixed with the CSS animation revealing the trash icon causes the animation to stop whilst the page scrolls, then the animation jumps into place making it look sloppy.

I know I can use a preventDefault parameter however this prevents the body of the page scrolling if the user scrolls the page by touching any of the list items, of which they cover a large portion of the screen so this would not work.

Does anyone know of a way to tidy this up at all so the user can swipe to delete an item and see a nice smooth animation whilst also being able to scroll the page when desired, as in iOS.

The app can be [played with here to see the effect](http://martinburdon.co.uk/Decisions).

Simply create a few questions so that the page can scroll and then go to answer a question so you can swipe to delete a question.

Thanks for any help,
Martin